# How to shorten long require list for backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I've started a JavaScript application using Backbone.js and Require.js. The application displays different top-level views - searching items, editing different aspects of items, connecting items to each other. Each view is displayed exclusively.

The file for the router module looks like this:

```
define([
  'backbone',
  'myapp' 
  'views/search',
  'views/edit1', 
  'views/edit2', 
  'views/connect'], 
function(Backbone, App, SearchView, EditView1, Editview2, ConnectView) {

  return Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "search": "doSearch",
      "edit1":  "doEdit1",
      // more routes here
    },
    doSearch: function() {
      App.main.show(new SearchView()); // Marionette.js regions
    },
    doEditView1: function() {
      App.main.show(new EditView1());
    },
    // etc.
  });
});
```

In my code there are much more views. Is there a way to cut down the long require list of views to one object? Maybe through another architecture or some require.js trick?

Maybe I'm too influenced by the Symfony 2 concept of what a "router" is?

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this problem myself.

One simple solution would be to define a module with all your views in it, and then just include *that* as a dependency:

views/all.js

```
define([
  'views/search',
  'views/edit1', 
  'views/edit2', 
  'views/connect'], 
function(SearchView, EditView1, EditView2, ConnectView) {

    return {
      "EditView1": EditView1,
      "EditView2": EditView2,
      "ConnectView": ConnectView
      "SearchView": SearchView
    };
});
```

Then in your router module you can include views/all as a dependency assigned to a variable `Views`, and call any view as `Views.EditView1`, `Views.EditView2`, etc.:

```
define([
  'backbone',
  'myapp', 
  'views/all'], 
function(Backbone, App, Views) {
  ...

  doSearch: function() {
    App.main.show(new Views.SearchView());
  },

  ...
});
```

I've never actually tried this but I think it would work.

Answer (score 1):

On a syntactical level, Require.js also supports the '[simplified CommonJS wrapping](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar)'. Obviously this cannot help you avoid long lists of dependencies (as @shioyama's suggestion does) but will minimise the risk of mismatched dependency names with named function arguments and aid in keeping things tidy(er).